# SQL String Delimited by Comma into a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a number string that is delimited by comma. Sample: `123, 213, 312, 231`
And I need to process each number in a SQL cursor. So my first step is to put each number in a table like so:

```
DECLARE @t AS TABLE(string nvarchar(100));
```

The problem however is I do not know how to split the string, remove the comma and insert each number in the table I created at the same time. I can try to monkey try hard code it but I know it will not be beautiful and fast. Please help me!

NOTE: I'm using SQL Server 2012 but it will be nice if the function supports SQL Server 2008 R2 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rextester: http://rextester.com/ZCU48506

function: Jeff Moden's Split N4k

```
create function dbo.DelimitedSplitN4K (
    @pString nvarchar(4000)
  , @pDelimiter nchar(1)
  )
returns table with schemabinding as
return
  with e1(n) as (
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all 
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all 
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1
  )
  , e2(n) as (select 1 from e1 a, e1 b)
  , e4(n) as (select 1 from e2 a, e2 b)
  , cteTally(n) as (select top (isnull(datalength(@pString)/2,0))
      row_number() over (order by (select null)) from e4)
  , cteStart(n1) as (select 1 union all 
      select t.n+1 from cteTally t where substring(@pString,t.n,1) = @pDelimiter)
  , cteLen(n1,l1) as(select s.n1
  ,   isnull(nullif(charindex(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.n1),0)-s.n1,4000)
    from cteStart s
  )
 select ItemNumber = row_number() over(order by l.n1)
      , Item       = substring(@pString, l.n1, l.l1)
   from cteLen l;
go
```

query:

```
declare @sample nvarchar (64) = '123,213,312,231'

select * from dbo.DelimitedSplitN4K(@sample,',')
```

results

```
+------------+------+
| ItemNumber | Item |
+------------+------+
|          1 |  123 |
|          2 |  213 |
|          3 |  312 |
|          4 |  231 |
+------------+------+
```

splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Comment: Wow this looks amazing. Thanks a lot for linking this custom tool! Will mark as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You may use XML function since it's faster.

First, create the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION stringDilimitedToTableXML
(   
    @str VARCHAR(4000),
    @delimiter nchar(1)
)
RETURNS @Result TABLE(Value BIGINT)
AS
BEGIN

    Declare @x XML 
    select @x = cast('<A>' + replace(@str,@delimiter,'</A><A>') + '</A>' as xml)

    INSERT INTO @Result
        SELECT t.value('.', 'int') as inVal
        FROM @x.nodes('/A') as x(t)

    RETURN

END
GO
```

Call the function on query:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(4000) = '2879,2880,2881,2892,2893,2894'

SELECT * FROM dbo.stringDilimitedToTableXML( @str, ',')
```

Results:

```
Value
--------------------
2879
2880
2881
2892
2893
2894

(6 row(s) affected)
```

Link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amitjet/2009/12/11/convert-comma-separated-string-to-table-4-different-approaches/

[sql](/questions/tagged/sql) [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) [string](/questions/tagged/string) [sql-server-2012](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012) [sql-server-2008-r2](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008-r2)